# Top-bar achievements dialog is showing twice the real rep. points I've earned for one of my answers

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

Currently I have earned $78$ rep. points for [Prove no real number satisfies $x^{2} = -1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675527/prove-no-real-number-satisfies-x2-1/675542#675542), but the top-bar dialog (And only there) shows $+156$, and It's used for 'Today' total as well. It was $x \cdot 2$ for this question when I had less up votes as well.

[image]

Comment: Why the -1.....?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @robjohn good enough..?

Comment: Thanks. No one, possibly with the exception of the community team or the developers, can see what you see. It might prove useful to the developers who are looking into this. I will note that I last saw you had 8 up and 1 downvote which would normally be 78 points (in case that is useful to the developers).

Comment: @robjohn mind telling me who's behind that downvote you mentioned? ;)

Comment: 1. voting is private 2. I don't have access to that information (see 1.)

Comment: Interestingly enough, the rep bar graph in Dror's user account is accurate.

Comment: @anorton yep, I mentioned that in the post above. The only place with miscalculation is the top-bar